# How to invoke debug and release ios framework in a program?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am now building a APP for iPad, and this APP will call a framework that was created by myself. For the framework, I build a Debug version and Release version, and put them in different folders as they share the same name. When I invoke the framework, I add it manually by selecting `Build Phases-> Link Binary With Libraries-> Add`.  So if I want to build APP Debug version, which calls the Debug framework, I have to remove the Release framework and then add the Debug framework. I do not think it is a good solution. What I expect is that I put the debug and release framework in different fold and the APP will call the right folder based on its configuration. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Why you need debug version also?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup here. **Targets** > **edit scheme**

[image]